# In Spark structured streaming how do I output complete aggregations to an external source like a REST service

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The task I am trying to perform is to aggregate the count of values from a dimension (field) in a DataFrame, perform some statistics like average, max, min, etc then output the aggregates to an external system by making an API call. I am using a watermark of say 30 seconds with a window size of 10 seconds. I made these sizes small to make it easier for me to test and debug the system.

The only method I have found for making API calls is to use a `ForeachWriter`. My problem is that the `ForeachWriter` executes at the partition level and only produces an aggregate per partition. So far I haven't found a way to get the rolled up aggregates other than to coalesce to 1 which is a way to slow for my streaming application.

I have found that if I use the file based sink such as the Parquet writer to HDFS that the code produces real aggregations. It also performs very well. What I really need is to achieve this same result but calling an API rather than writing to a file system.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried this with Spark 2.2.2 and Spark 2.3 and get the same behavior.

Here is a simplified code fragment to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
val valStream = streamingDF
  .select(
    $"event.name".alias("eventName"),
    expr("event.clientTimestamp / 1000").cast("timestamp").as("eventTime"),
    $"asset.assetClass").alias("assetClass")
  .where($"eventName" === 'MyEvent')
  .withWatermark("eventTime", "30 seconds")
  .groupBy(window($"eventTime", "10 seconds", $"assetClass", $"eventName")
  .agg(count($"eventName").as("eventCount"))
  .select($"window.start".as("windowStart"), $"window.end".as("windowEnd"), $"assetClass".as("metric"), $"eventCount").as[DimAggregateRecord]
  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", config.checkpointPath)
  .outputMode(config.outputMode)

val session = (if(config.writeStreamType == AbacusStreamWriterFactory.S3) {
    valStream.format(config.outputFormat)
    .option("path", config.outputPath)
  }
  else {
    valStream.foreach(--- this is my DimAggregateRecord ForEachWriter ---)
  }).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question.  I found that repartitioning by the window start time did the trick. It shuffles the data so that all rows with the same group and windowStart time are on the same executor. The code below produces a file for each group window interval.  It also performs quite well.  I don't have exact numbers but it produces aggregates in less time than the window interval of 10 seconds.

```
val valStream = streamingDF
  .select(
    $"event.name".alias("eventName"),
    expr("event.clientTimestamp / 1000").cast("timestamp").as("eventTime"),
    $"asset.assetClass").alias("assetClass")
  .where($"eventName" === 'MyEvent')
  .withWatermark("eventTime", "30 seconds")
  .groupBy(window($"eventTime", "10 seconds", $"assetClass", $"eventName")
  .agg(count($"eventName").as("eventCount"))
  .select($"window.start".as("windowStart"), $"window.end".as("windowEnd"), $"assetClass".as("metric"), $"eventCount").as[DimAggregateRecord]

  .repartition($"windowStart")  // <-------- this line produces the desired result

  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", config.checkpointPath)
  .outputMode(config.outputMode)

val session = (if(config.writeStreamType == AbacusStreamWriterFactory.S3) {
    valStream.format(config.outputFormat)
    .option("path", config.outputPath)
  }
  else {
    valStream.foreach(--- this is my DimAggregateRecord ForEachWriter ---)
  }).start()
```